# Work Permit Visa for Canada

Tags: canada

I want to work in Canada on a work permit visa. Is there any work permit visa in Canada like USA H1B?

Answer (score 1):

The Government of Canada web site has a volume of information on ways to [live and work to Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/index.asp).

> **[Immigrate as a skilled worker through Express Entry](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/index.asp)**
>
> We choose skilled immigrants as permanent residents based on their ability to settle in Canada and take part in our economy. Our system to manage how people with skilled work experience apply to immigrate to Canada is called Express Entry.

Comment: I am providing [http://carvinc.com/erp-training-in-chennai.php] 'Microsoft Dynamics training in Chennai'. and i want to settle in canada.Please could you give number and mail-id for further discussion?